# Is proving "If $C⊆D⊆Y$, then $f^{-1}(C) ⊆ f^{-1}(D)$" done correctly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> **Definition 9** Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a function, and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of X and Y, respectively.
>
> (a) The image of $A$ under $f$, which we denote $f(A)$, is the set of all images $f(x)$ such that $x∈A$.
> (b) The inverse image of B under f, which we denote $f^{-1}(B)$, is the set of all images of y in B.

In symbols, $f (A) =\{ f (x) \mid x\in A\}$,   $f^{-1}(B)=\{x \mid f (x)\in B\}$

> **Theorem 9** Let f: $X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. Then
> (d) If  $C⊆D⊆Y$, then $f^{-1}(C) ⊆ f^{-1}(D)$
> Source: Set Theory, You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T. Lin

The author leaves the proof of the theorem to the reader.
I'm not sure about my proof process in the part justified by the definition of inverse image.  Is there something to be corrected, or is it enough by itself?

[my proof]
$x ∈ f^{-1}(C)$
$\Leftrightarrow f (x) \in C$  $∵$Def. of Inverse Image
$\Rightarrow f(x) \in D$  $∵$given assumption.
$\Leftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}(D)$ $∵$Def. of Inverse Image

Thus
$x \in f^{-1}(C) \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(D)$
≡$f^{-1}(C) ⊆ f^{-1}(D)$ $∵$ definition of subset

Q.E.D

Comment: Your proof is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is complete, I see no part that could be improved.